# Can I use two 20-inch samsung S20A300B monitors with my laptop?

Tags: laptop, video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have two Samsung NV755 S20A300B monitors and a Gateway NV75S05h laptop which has an AMD Radeon HD 6540G2 video card.  The laptop itself only has an HDMI port and a VGA port.

Is it possible to have my laptop screen off and have both monitors on and running different things? I know I can run one off of the VGA port, but I'm wondering if I can run the second with an HDMI to VGA converter cable.

Answer (score 0):

At work I use a laptop which has a VGA port and a HDMI port. - My monitors have VGA/DVI/HDMI ports in them and so my configuration is VGA -> VGA and HDMI -> HDMI.

This works perfectly for a dual screen setup and I can't think of a reason why your laptop would not support it. Just make sure you get the adapter you need if your monitor(s) don't have HDMI connections

Comment: Ok awesome.  The monitors don't have hdmi inputs so hopefully the right cable will do the trick.  In order for both monitors to be on though the laptop screen must be off right?

Comment: @MitchSawyer Unless your Laptop/GFX card can support 3 output displays (Mine can't) then yes it will have to be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that exact set up, but yes you should be able to.

With the converter, everything should work.

Assuming you are using windows 7, once you connect the monitors it should be a fairly self explanatory once you right click on your desktop -> screen resolution -> detect monitors.

Sometimes you can just connect them, and you can use all 3 monitors (the laptop monitor, plus the 2 external).  On my computer if I set up all 3 monitors, I can just close my laptop and the exterior 2 work fine.  My last laptop, I actually had to go in and disable my laptop monitor (also in screen resolution).